# sqlplus client redirect remote results to a local file

Tags: sql, oracle, terminal, sqlplus

I'm accessing an oracle database remotely and I need to redirect results to a local csv file. I'm setting some options, a simple sql query statement and finally I redirect to a local file.
Based on this [link](http://www.orahow.com/2015/09/spool-sqlplus-output-to-excel-format.html) and [this](http://markstutpnt.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/spool-sqlplus-output-to-microsoft-excel.html) I did that:

```
./sqlplus user/password@host:1521/SID <<< "SET PAGESIZE 40000 FEEDBACK OFF MARKUP HTML ON select * from mytable where ROWNUM <= 10" >> test_file.xls
```

Doing that I get this Oracle error: SP2-0158: unknown SET option "select". The error is self explanatory. I know I need these set statements to format my output. Removing SET statement works fine but output.

To output, I don't insert SPOOL statement because the file will be generated on remote machine.

What do I need to do to get results to my local file?

Comment: I think you just need a semicolon between `ON` and `select`. A heredoc might be simpler to manage though. Why do you think spool outputs on the remote machine? It's a client command.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've tried before: SP2-0158: unknown SET option ";"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
./sqlplus user/password@host:1521/SID <<EOF >> test_file.xls
SET PAGESIZE 40000 FEEDBACK OFF MARKUP HTML ON 
select * from mytable where ROWNUM <= 10;
exit
EOF
```

Comment: @ser3515709 It works. What exactly EOF does in this case? And another one, the output comes of course, in html. My will is to generate an xls

Comment: It says redirect everything to the command until you find the word EOF.
it can be any word or caracter like <<FOO or <<!
Also the HTML output is what you ask whith MARKUP HTML ON, excel recognise the HTML so your file will open just fine in excel.